# lsp-rust: require + provide but still void-function

Tags: package, require, load

I am trying to use [lsp-rust](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-rust) package.
I installed it from melpa.
After I run it I got message in `*Messages*`:

```
Error loading autoloads: (void-function lsp-define-stdio-client)
```

There are two packages: `lsp-rust` and `lsp-mode` (both of them I install from melpa),

`lsp-define-stdio-client` defined in `lsp-mode`,
and was used in `lsp-rust`, code from `lsp-rust.el`:

```
(require 'lsp-mode)
...
;;;###autoload
(lsp-define-stdio-client 'rust-mode "rust" 'stdio
           #'lsp-rust--get-root
            "Rust Language Server"
           (lsp-rust--rls-command))
...
(provide 'lsp-rust)
```

If run `emacs --debug-init`, then problem happens in the first line of `.emacs`:

```
(package-initialize)
```

I not get it, why autoload of `lsp-rust` happened before `lsp-mode`,
execution of `autoload` functions not depend on `require` and `provide`?

**Update**

I can fix this issue, if I edit `~/.emacs.d/elpa/lsp-rust-20170421.326/lsp-rust-autoloads.el`, and change

```
(lsp-define-stdio-client 'rust-mode "rust" 'stdio #'lsp-rust--get-root "Rust Language Server" (lsp-rust--rls-command))
```

to

```
(require 'lsp-mode)
(require 'lsp-rust)
(lsp-define-stdio-client 'rust-mode "rust" 'stdio #'lsp-rust--get-root "Rust Language Server" (lsp-rust--rls-command))
```

In other words add `(require 'lsp-mode)` and `(require 'lsp-rust)` manually,
but this is temporary solution, untill `M-x list-packages` download new version of `lsp-rust`.

Comment: @Drew Sorry, not understand your advise. About `your file`, there is no my file here, all packages installed from melpa with `M-x list-packages`, and I suppose emacs 25 package manager put stuff into `load-path`.

Comment: Perhaps someone will have a specific answer for you. The package should take care of defining its autoloads correctly. I was guessing that perhaps it does not.

Comment: @Drew `lsp-define-stdio-client` is `defun`.

Comment: @Drew Looks like this is bug in `lsp-rust`, autoloaded code is `cut` from main elisp file, so `require` which import `lsp-define-stdio-client` is not executed.